# phpmailer ошибка

Tags: phpmailer

При отправке данных на почту получаю:

Ошибка: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

В логах получаю:

2022-06-19 15:56:54 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.mail.ru:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2022-06-19 15:56:54 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol [D:\progs\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\dist\phpmailer\SMTP.php line 394]
2022-06-19 15:56:54 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [D:\progs\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\dist\phpmailer\SMTP.php line 394]
2022-06-19 15:56:54 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.mail.ru:587 (Unknown error) [D:\progs\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\dist\phpmailer\SMTP.php line 394]
2022-06-19 15:56:54 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Ошибка: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

php код:

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

    require "phpmailer/Exception.php";
    require "phpmailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require "phpmailer/SMTP.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();                   // Отправка через SMTP
    $mail->Host   = 'smtp.mail.ru';  // Адрес SMTP сервера
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;          // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'testinfo@domain.by';
    $mail->Password   = 'prizrak';    // ваш пароль
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         // шифрование ssl
    $mail->Port       = 587;   
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;            // порт подключения
    
    $mail->setFrom('testinfo@domain.by', 'Иван Иванов');    // от кого
    $mail->addAddress('vasya_petrov@mail.ru', 'Вася Петров'); // кому
    
    $mail->Subject = 'Тест';
    $mail->msgHTML("<html><body>
                    <h1>Здравствуйте!</h1>
                    <p>Это тестовое письмо.</p>
                    </html></body>");
    // Отправляем
    if ($mail->send()) {
    echo 'Письмо отправлено!';
    } else {
    echo 'Ошибка: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

?>
```

Новые логи:

2022-06-19 16:35:18 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.mail.ru:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2022-06-19 16:35:18 Connection: opened
2022-06-19 16:35:18 SMTP INBOUND: "220 smtp3.mail.ru ESMTP ready (Looking for Mail for your domain? Visit https://biz.mail.ru)"
2022-06-19 16:35:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp3.mail.ru ESMTP ready (Looking for Mail for your domain? Visit https://biz.mail.ru)
2022-06-19 16:35:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO dist
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-smtp3.mail.ru"
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 73400320"
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2"
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp3.mail.ru250-SIZE 73400320250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2
2022-06-19 16:35:19 Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED
2022-06-19 16:35:19 Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN,XOAUTH2
2022-06-19 16:35:19 Requested auth method not available: 
2022-06-19 16:35:19 Auth method selected: LOGIN
2022-06-19 16:35:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SMTP INBOUND: "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2022-06-19 16:35:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: dGVzdEBkZXdwb2ludC5ieQ==
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SMTP INBOUND: "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2022-06-19 16:35:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2022-06-19 16:35:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: TDZlWEZ8RElMeA==
2022-06-19 16:35:20 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.0 NEOBHODIM parol prilozheniya https://help.mail.ru/mail/security/protection/external / Application password is REQUIRED"
2022-06-19 16:35:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.0 NEOBHODIM parol prilozheniya https://help.mail.ru/mail/security/protection/external / Application password is REQUIRED
2022-06-19 16:35:20 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.0 NEOBHODIM parol prilozheniya https://help.mail.ru/mail/security/protection/external / Application password is REQUIRED
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2022-06-19 16:35:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-06-19 16:35:20 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Bye"
2022-06-19 16:35:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
2022-06-19 16:35:20 Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Ошибка: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это особенность mail.ru.
Пароль от аккаунта mail.ru можно использовать только в "родных" приложениях и браузере. Для других приложений и почтовых клиентов надо создавать отдельные пароли для авторизации.

> Чтобы войти в ящик Mail.ru через почтовую программу, обычный пароль от ящика не подойдёт — вам понадобится специальный пароль для внешнего приложения
> [Справка](https://help.mail.ru/mail/mailer/trouble)

Answer (score 1):

Из логов мы узнаем, что у нас ошибка именно с подключением.

Значит следует узнать все ли параметры для отправки верны.
Возможное решение:

**Сменить порт.**

Открываем документацию: https://help.mail.ru/mail/mailer/trouble/error

Необходимый нам порт SMTP — 465 (протокол шифрования SSL/TLS)

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Comment: а счас что, пороль неверный? В вопросе логи, посмотрите пожалуйста